# Rear hub-adjuster thing - What does it do?

Tags: parts

I bought a basic wheel set for a hack bike project.  The rear wheel has a single speed cog, and a dangly adjuster thingy - maybe 2 inches long.  What is that for?

Comment: Could you perhaps include a picture or a link to something similar?

Comment: This really needs a picture or a more detailed description. There are several things that could conceivably be dangling back there...

Comment: Hi Guys, ill add a photo tonight when i get home from work. Thanks for pitching in.  It is definitely not a internal hub or coaster brake.

Comment: Given that it is a single speed, it could be a chain tensioner. But as the other commenters have said, a picture would help.

Answer (score 4):

The dangly adjuster thing is most likely the toggle chain for an internally geared hub!

[image: 3 speed hub]

The tension on that chain shifts the hub internally (rather than through a derailleur and cogset). Bike hacks with three-speed hubs are quite common, but get very complicated. [Here](http://sheldonbrown.com/sturmey-archer.html) is some information on Sturmey Archer hubs courtesy of Sheldon Brown.

Below is a picture of the toggle chain and rod which is attached to the inside of the hub. Good luck!

[image]

Comment: Also, an alternative to @Tom77's suggestion of a coaster brake, it could also be a drum brake which will have a reaction arm and an actuation arm. They can be installed on front or rear hubs and are frequently cable actuated (as opposed to a coaster brake's pedal-actuation.)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a coaster brake (operated by pedalling backwards), if this is the case then the dangly thing is the [reaction arm](http://sheldonbrown.com/coaster-brakes.html#reaction).